# Since Kaliyuga itself feels like hell (naraka), do souls still go to hell after death?

Tags: death, kali-yuga, afterlife, naraka, swarga

Are swarga and naraka any different in Kali Yuga?

I mean quality of life itself will deteriorate so much in Kali Yuga that it will seem like hell on Earth so will there be another hell after death to be experienced in this yuga? If not, where will all the human souls go after death? Do they take birth immediately?

There are some scriptures that say that after death people go to swarga or naraka and are reborn according to their deeds but I think all these stories are from previous yugas. Do the same rules apply to Kali Yuga?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Judgment All will be judged on the upcoming Judgement day/Qayamat/Yam-ad-Din/(Day of Yamraj)

Comment: @Nitin, that is wrong. there is no 'Last' judgement in Hinduism. There is judgement after death, but it's not the last, because of many births and deaths - after each death, judgement will be given, taken to hell or heaven, and return to earth, and cycle repeats

Comment: Your question philosphy is not suited to hinduism!! this must be one of western concept!!! Sanatan Dharma doesnt have this!!!

Comment: What is meant by going to heaven or hell 'between birth and dead'?

Comment: I just meant where will human soul go after deadth in kalyug and before taking birth again in kalyug.Like there are scriptures saying after deadth person goes to swarg aur nark and then again takes birth according to his/her deeds but all the stories are from previous yugas.Will this be same for kalyug??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the people (with bad Karma) will still go to the hells in Kali Yuga.

In fact, Puranas, like Bhavisya Purana, state that hells will over-populated in Kali Yuga. So, that means, compared to the other three Yugas, more people will have to visit hells, in Kali Yuga.

> At the end of the Kali's second half there would neither by the
>   institutions of marriages, nor Kingships, nor any social reformer and
>   not even a Karma Karta! The World would be full of the progeny of
>   Bhogi Simha and Keli Simha and this kind of a situation devoid of
>   customs and social norms woud prevail for one and quarter lakh years!!
>   In the Third Quarter of Kali Yuga, the average age of human beings
>   would be twenty six years maximum;They would be too lustful and
>   produce too many children and resort to affairs with co-males and
>   animals!....... In the fourth phase of Kali Yuga the maximum age of
>   humans would not exceed tewnty years and live like water-beasts and
>   animals; **hells like Tamistra and worse kinds of frightening Places
>   of Retribution would be over-populated**

Source: The Book ["Essence of Bhavishya Purana"](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/bhavishya/bookview.php?chapnum=31)